# ¿Cómo hago para sumar un array de meses en Java?

Tags: java

Tengo que sumar el ingreso mensual (ingresos-gastos) de un array de los 12 meses en Java para obtener el ingreso anual, pero lo estoy haciendo mal y no me lo tira

```
 public class RentaAnual {

    static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    static PrintStream out = System.out;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String[] mes = {"enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "setiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"};
        for (int i = 0; i < mes.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("Ingrese los ingresos brutos mensuales de " + mes[i] + " : ");
            double ingresosBrutosMensuales = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

            System.out.println("Ingrese los costos y gastos mensuales de " + mes[i] + " : ");
            int costosYgastos = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

            double rentaNetaMensual = (ingresosBrutosMensuales - costosYgastos);
            double rentaNetaAnual = sum rentaNetaMensual[i];

if (rentaNetaAnual > 3000) {
                rentaNetaAnual = rentaNetaAnual * 0.10;
                System.out.println("La renta neta con los impuestos incluidos es de: " + rentaNetaAnual);
```

Comment: Añade el código entero, con este código no te puedo ayudar demasiado, aunque si que te voy a decir que declarar las variables dentro del 'for' no suele ser una buena idea, y creo que es la causa de tu problema. Si subes el código entero te podría ayudar de verdad.

Comment: Acabo de editar mi pregunta para que la puedas ver mejor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo con tu código me figuro que lo que buscas es esto:

```
static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(System.in));
static PrintStream out = System.out;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    double rentaNetaAnual=0;
    double ingresosBrutosMensuales;
    double rentaNetaMensual;
    int costosYgastos;
    String[] mes = {"enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "setiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"};
    for (int i = 0; i < mes.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("Ingrese los ingresos brutos mensuales de " + mes[i] + " : ");
         ingresosBrutosMensuales = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        System.out.println("Ingrese los costos y gastos mensuales de " + mes[i] + " : ");
        costosYgastos = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        rentaNetaMensual = (ingresosBrutosMensuales - costosYgastos);
        rentaNetaAnual +=  rentaNetaMensual;
        System.out.println(rentaNetaAnual);
    }

}
```

Como te he puesto en el comentario, tu problema es que declaras las variables dentro del `for`, eso no es una buena práctica, siempre fuera del `for`, ya que por cada iteración estás reservando un espacio de memoria.

Más cosas a comentar, veo tu código incompleto porque... ¿Qué pasa si meto letras en vez de números? ¿y si no meto nada?, prueba si quieres, te va a dar un error en consola. Todo eso tienes que controlarlo por medio de excepciones.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Acabo de probar el algoritmo y ya me funciona, lo de las excepciones pensé que lo estaba controlando con "throws IOException" pero al parecer cuando hago la prueba que me dices vos me tira el error de consola

Comment: De hecho agregué una parte a mi algoritmo para ver si logro agregar un impuesto a la rentaNetaAnual y no me lo permitió "if (rentaNetaAnual > 3000) {
                rentaNetaAnual = rentaNetaAnual * 0.10;
                System.out.println("La renta neta con los impuestos incluidos es de: " + rentaNetaAnual);"

Comment: Con el throws simplemente estás diciendo que tira la excepción, pero no la tratas, entonces lo que pasa en la consola es lo que tu has dicho, que la está tirando y entonces se pinta en la consola todo el error, para tratar las excepciones hay que encapsularlas en un `try` `catch`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Ya entendí mejor el problema, es súper bueno saber eso, apenas estoy empezando a estudiar programación y no entendiendo muchas cosas básicas